# problems with number_format and negative numbers

Tags: php, number-formatting

Right now I'm storing numbers as a double(11,3) in my database.  Some of the numbers can be larger negatives.  The one I'm playing with right now is -3000.000

When I use number_format on just 3000.000 it returns 3,000
When I use number_format on -3000.000 it returns -3

Any ideas why this is happening and what I can do to fix it?  I'm kind of at a loss right now as to why this is happening.

Thanks,

Jeff

**EDIT:** I got it to work with the following code:

```
$number = abs($row['Amount']) * -1; $final = number_format($number,2);
```

Now why that would work and not:

```
$final = number_format($row['Amount'],2);
```

I haven't got a clue, but at least I found a solution, thanks for the help :)

Comment: This `php -R 'echo number_format(-3000.000);'` returns `-3,000`. Can you confirm that the DB is sending the right info?

Comment: which DBMS? There were bugs in some PHP versions regarding some databases - PHP did not retrieve some numeric values properly.

Comment: Just did this: echo number_format(3000.000,2) * -1; and got -3...I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
if($input<0){
  $number = abs($input);
  $result = number_format($number) * -1;
}else {
  $result = number_format($input);
}
```

Comment: Even with this I'm still getting 3: echo number_format(3000.000,2) * -1;  I don't understand wth is happening....

Comment: See @salathe. You are taking a string and multiplying it by -1. The comma in `"3,000"` will cause the math operation to be `3 * -1`.

Comment: The suggested code will **not** work since `"3,000.00" * -1` causes the string to get type juggled (to `3`) before the multiplication.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out, but I picked his/her answer as the correct one b/c it did lead me to the answer :)

Comment: So you marked an incorrect answer to be correct... I think a more accurate choice would be to write your own correct answer and mark that as correct. This will live on the internet and could mislead many people over the next few years.

Answer (score 2):

The result from `number_format(-3000.000, 2)` is the **string**, `"-3,000.00"`.

If you don't get that, please update the question with code that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your number is extracted as -3000 from database. Otherwise previous answers and comments are good.

Comment: Yeah it is which is why I came here.  I've sort of got Shameer's version working, still one bug to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

based on Shameer's suggestion, I came to this solution.

trailing zeros on negative values will be returned (probably as expected):

```
if($input < 0){
    return number_format(0-abs($input), 2, ',', '');
}
else {
    return number_format((float)$input, 2, ',', '');
}
```